# How to make ediff-patch-file strip leading path components?

Tags: ediff

I have a multi-file patch and ediff-patch-file doesn't find the files unless I manually remove all of the "a/" and "b/" prefixes from the patch first. In other words, it acts like "patch -p0" when I want "patch -p1". How do I tell ediff to do what I want?

Example:

```
diff --git a/src/java/main/com/example/player/PlayerApplication.java b/src/java/main/com/example/player/PlayerApplication.java
--- a/src/java/main/com/example/player/PlayerApplication.java
+++ b/src/java/main/com/example/player/PlayerApplication.java
@@ -907,6 +907,7 @@
```

Version: GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the code of `ediff-patch-file`, you will find it calls `ediff-patch-file-internal` which basically just calls GNU Patch (https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/patch-Options.html)

Here is code quoted from `ediff-patch-file-internal`:

```
(call-process-region
 (point-min) (point-max)
 shell-file-name
 t   ; delete region (which contains the patch
 t   ; insert output (patch diagnostics) in current buffer
 nil ; don't redisplay
 shell-command-switch   ; usually -c
 (format "%s %s %s %s"
     ediff-patch-program
     ediff-patch-options
     ediff-backup-specs
     (expand-file-name true-source-filename))
 ))
```

You can tweak `ediff-patch-options` whose default value is "-f".

So the easiest setup is `(setq ediff-patch-options "-f -p1")`.